# Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried: xx.xx.xx.xx:5701, xx.xx.xx.xx:5702, xx.xx.xx.xx:5703

Tags: c#, hazelcast.net

Did Hazelcast cluster setup in AKS using [helm](https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/tree/master/stable/hazelcast) as unisocket client and the setup completed successfully. Able to access the man center without any issues and see the nodes up and running.

The problem is when trying to access from c# client

```
//HazleCast
var hazelClientConfig = new ClientConfig();
hazelClientConfig.GetNetworkConfig().SetSmartRouting(false);
hazelClientConfig.GetNetworkConfig().AddAddress("xx.xx.xx.xx");
services.AddSingleton(hazelClientConfig);

services.AddTransient(x =>
    {
        var hazelClientConfig = x.GetRequiredService<ClientConfig>();
        return HazelcastClient.NewHazelcastClient(hazelClientConfig);
    });
```

getting this error:

> Unable to connect to any address in the config!

The following addresses were tried: xx.xx.xx.xx:5701, xx.xx.xx.xx:5702, xx.xx.xx.xx:5703

Man center shows that the service is listening on 5701

Comment: Firewall settings?

Comment: nothing, i am able to access the man center on 8080 running on the same AKS cluster without any whitelisting

Comment: You do not have a server running.  See quick starts in you link.  Either you did not start the server or the server closed due to an error.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting 6 hours figured out and fixed the problem..

Use this helm command : helm install hazelcast --set service.type=LoadBalancer,service.clusterIP="",**image.tag=3.12** hazelcast/hazelcast

By default it was using latest hazelcast image which is not compatible with c# client yet so added a tag to pull the one which is compatible.